# Bose QC45 Stopped working as mic

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone, bose

I have been using my Bose QC45 on my work machine for video confrencing over Teams for a few months without issue and then one morning a while back they will no longer function as a mic, only headphones.

When I go into the sound settings I can see the headset profile, but it is disconnected and when I attempt to connect it, nothing happens.

[image: Windows Sound Settings with Disconnected Headset]

I have unpaired, reconnected, and even erased all device history off the headset, but to no avail. The computer is fully up to date on Windows 10. I've followed every troubleshooting article that I can find and so far nothing has changed. I'm sure there is a setting somewhere that needs to be changed as these were working great for a while and still work great when paired with my phone, but I just can't put my finger on it at this point. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect them to another system?  This looks like a possible hardware issue

Comment: If you've not yet tried it, 1. Turn Aiplane Mode on and off 2. *Remove* the Bluetooth device, either using Device Manager, CMD, PowerShekll, etc.: https://www.asavvyweb.com/windows/how-to-fix-cant-remove-bluetooth-device-on-windows-10 and https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/22049-how-completely-remove-bluetooth-device-win-10-a.html , then reconnect.

Comment: I don't believe it is a hardware issue as I had this same issue with a previous headset (Bose QC35) several months ago, but for the life of me I can't remember what I did to fix it. I've seen several forums where other Bose users are having the same issue, but most never get resolved or the resolution doesn't work for my case.

Comment: Been facing the same exact problem for about a month or so. I can hear everyone in Teams, but nobody can hear me. And the test call is just weird, microphone doesn't work there either, but the audio also mutes when it's trying to access the mic. I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation as you-- mine stopped working all of a sudden. They don't act like they used to. In pairing mode, I used to hear a guitar strum echo sound over and over, then all of a sudden it's a female voice saying "ready to connect" and nothing else. These things are such hot garbage. They lasted *just* long enough to outlive the warranty period before falling apart, and support is a total joke.

I removed all Bluetooth devices from my laptop, removed the headphones from my phone via the Bose app, then did a hard reset of headphones (hold switch to right + push button, light will flash white, then after 30 seconds will flash blue). Re-paired headphones, but still nothing worked-- it was only registering itself as an audio device and selecting headset microphone would mute the audio. Then I got my first BSOD in a decade, for `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` (go figure). Rebooted. Still didn't work.

What fixed the issue was removing my Dell monitor (of all things) from the `Settings > Bluetooth > Audio` section (not the dialog box you show). I don't even know why it was listed in the Bluetooth section since it has no Bluetooth capabilities, though it does have speakers. Disconnected and reconnected headphones, and now I seem to have both *stereo* audio on calls as well as a functional headset microphone (hasn't worked this well since the day I bought the damn things. Hope they don't start popping and crackling again).

Note that at this time, my headphones are only connected to my laptop, not my phone, and no Bose app currently in the loop. The multi-device feature has been nothing but a headache for me.

Comment: If I'm on the right screen, that is Bluetooth & other devices, so it lists all audio devices, which is why your monitor would be displaying in there. I happened to have 2 monitors in that list, but unfortunately removing them didn't fix the issue for me.